# Two lasers between two mirrors

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

What if we have a corridor comprised of two parallel mirrors?

```
|          |
|          |
|          |
|          |
|          |
|          |
|          |
|          |
|          |
|          |
```

Now, we shine a laser down it...

```
|  \       |
|   \      |
|    \     |
|     \    |
|      \   |
|       \  |
|        \ |
|         \|
|         /|
|        / |
```

Oh, look. It bounced, towards the end, there.

What if we draw two lasers BUT going in the opposite direction?

```
|  \    /  |
|   \  /   |
|    \/    |
|    /\    |
|   /  \   |
|  /    \  |
| /      \ |
|/        \|
|\        /|
| \      / |
```

Hmm, they didn't seem to meet, there. That's convenient. What happens if both lasers take up the same space?

```
|  \     / |
|   \   /  |
|    \ /   |
|     X    |
|    / \   |
|   /   \  |
|  /     \ |
| /       \|
|/        /|
|\       / |
```

I guess that was pretty obvious, huh?

---

Drawing these diagrams by hand is pretty laborious (trust me on this). Perhaps some code could do it for us?

- Write some code to output two parallel mirrors, with two bouncing, intersecting lasers.
- Input (all integers):

  - The width of the corridor
  - The length of the corridor
  - Starting position of the right-going laser (zero-indexed, must be less than width)
  - Starting position of the left-going laser (zero-indexed, must be less than width)
- Process

  - If a laser is right going, it will be drawn one space to the right on the following line.
  - If a laser is left going, it will be drawn one space to the left on the following line.
  - If a laser can not take it's sideways step, it will change it's direction, but not it's position.
  - If both laser are at the same index, print an upper-case X at that index.
- Output

  - A string with multiple lines
  - Each line starts and ends with a pipe character (|)
  - Right-going laser are denoted by a back slash (\)
  - Left-going laser are denoted by a forward slash (/)
  - The intersection of two lasers is denoted by an upper-case X.
- Any language
- I'd like to see [TIO](https://tio.run/) links
- Attempt to fix it in the smallest number of bytes

---

## Test cases

width: 6
length: 10
right-going: 1
left-going: 4

```
| \  / |
|  \/  |
|  /\  |
| /  \ |
|/    \|
|\    /|
| \  / |
|  \/  |
|  /\  |
| /  \ |
```

width: 6
length: 10
right-going: 0
left-going: 1

```
|\/    |
|/\    |
|\ \   |
| \ \  |
|  \ \ |
|   \ \|
|    \/|
|    /\|
|   / /|
|  / / |
```

width: 4
length: 10
right-going: 2
left-going: 0

```
|/ \ |
|\  \|
| \ /|
|  X |
| / \|
|/  /|
|\ / |
| X  |
|/ \ |
|\  \|
```

width: 20
length: 5
right-going: 5
left-going: 15

```
|     \         /    |
|      \       /     |
|       \     /      |
|        \   /       |
|         \ /        |
```

width: 5
length: 6
right-going: 2
left-going: 2

```
|  X  |
| / \ |
|/   \|
|\   /|
| \ / |
|  X  |
```

width: 1
length: 2
right-going: 0
left-going: 0

```
|X|
|X|
```

Comment: Suggested edge case: width: 1, length: whatever, right: 0, left: 0

Comment: @Arnauld |X| ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 40 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
àù@○⌡┼PY¼îαφu^·A☺°É⌠■╟¡Åt^◘v(µ╩Ñ♣t{╓○xß╦
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=85974009f5c55059ac8ce0ed755efa4101f890f4fec7ad8f745e087628e6caa505747bd60978e1cb&i=6+[1+4]+10%0A6+[0+1]+10%0A5+[2+2]+6%0A1+[0+0]+2&a=1&m=2)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AWEAnv9zdGF4///DoMO5QOKXi@KMoeKUvFBZwrzDrs6xz4Z1XsK3QeKYusKww4nijKDilqDilZ/CocOFdF7il5h2KMK14pWpw5HimaN0e@KVk@KXi3jDn@KVpv//NSBbMiAyXSA2)

Pretty sure this can be further golfed.

Input is given in the form of `width [right-going left-going] length`(per comment by @EngineerToast).

ASCII equivalent:

```
xHXdmzx);hi+x%Y92&;Hi-x%cy=41*47+&2ME:R\{|+m'||S
```

Comment: Might want to note the input format as `width [right-going left-going] length`

Answer (score 18):

## JavaScript (ES6), 149 bytes

Takes input in currying syntax `(w)(h)([a,b])`.

```javascript
w=>h=>g=(p,d=[1,-1],s=Array(w).fill` `)=>h--?`|${p=p.map((x,i)=>~(k=d[i],s[x]='/X\\'[x-p[i^1]?k+1:1],x+=k)&&x<w?x:x+(d[i]=-k)),s.join``}|
`+g(p,d):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc7BToNAEAbge5/CgykzYRdZUnogTolvYbLFLCkFtyC7ASNrrL46Lo03vM43/z9zKT/K8TRo@857U53nmuaJDq90aAgsq0gKxkXBRnoahvITJoxq3XXqTqHf4jxX1/svSzZ6Ky2AY9qPf6ClSmofkq6g4OH5eAyk41bqF1HkbSgyX@hCanG7dY9T7jIXwhIg3iKyMboY3Sv1fd2osFmewCwI5pPpR9Odo840UMMeQcQI/rtdgbj5H2Mm1rj7w4TFa0y8pB5TJtK1etnfksnaBEJyO7m0zr8)

#### Commented

```javascript
w => h =>                  // w = width, h = height
  g = (                    // g = recursive function taking:
    p,                     //   p[] = array holding the point coordinates
    d = [1, -1],           //   d[] = directions
    s = Array(w).fill` `   //   s = array of w spaces (we can't use a string because it's
  ) =>                     //       immutable in JS)
    h-- ?                  // if we haven't reached the last row yet:
      `|${                 //   append the left pipe
      p = p.map((x, i) =>  //   for each x at position i in p[]:
        ~(k = d[i],        //     k = direction for this point
          s[x] = '/X\\'[   //     insert either '/', 'X' or '\' at position x in s
            x - p[i ^ 1] ? //     if p[0] != p[1]:
              k + 1        //       use the direction
            :              //     else:
              1            //       force 'X'
          ], x += k        //     add k to x
        ) &&               //     if the result is not equal to -1
        x < w ?            //     and is less than w:
          x                //       use the current value of x
        :                  //     else:
          x + (d[i] = -k)  //       change the direction and restore the initial value of x
      ),                   //   end of map()
      s.join``}|\n` +      //   join and append s; append the right bar and a linefeed
      g(p, d)              //   followed by the result of a recursive call
    :                      // else:
      ''                   //   stop recursion
```

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 119 bytes

```python
w,l,a,b=input()
exec"print'|%s|'%''.join(' \/X'[sum(i==k%(2*w)for k in[a,~b]+[~a,b]*2)]for i in range(w));a+=1;b-=1;"*l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7bCoMwDIbvfYpSkLbaHVrUi4nvMXBe6HCz01WpihuIr@5SZZDTlz8k6b5D1Wq5TpVqSiQu5ae8I4MxXife8JwXidLdOFDmWAV3RumBzG4/E5eQ46tVmhJ0O11J2o9vqpKkdqn0JvZoDaqR0mnOlyLz0wVWZZ5kmRUUCMjk@lnSibE49xMRFwcI2GvW7YRjP6ARR@IMzlHAnD/ZBlCwk4QGkIQy3EyEgJCjTZMAYp@ygz8)

Comment: Can you not golf `\\/` to `\/`? Even though the backslash is interpreted twice, it will still not escape the slash.

Comment: @JonathanFrech You're right, I thought being in a string-in-string would fail, but it indeed doesn't escape either time.

Comment: Oh jeez, my solution got painfully close to this idea -- working modulo 2w makes a lot of sense in retrospect. Very clever!

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>187</s> <s>181</s> <s>179</s> <s>177</s> <s>174</s> <s>172</s> 171 bytes

```python
def f(w,l,a,b,A=1,B=-1):
 while l:l-=1;print'|%s|'%''.join(' \X/'[[0,A,B,2][(i==a)+2*(i==b)]]for i in range(w));a,A=[a,a+A,-A,A][-1<a+A<w::2];b,B=[b,b+B,-B,B][-1<b+B<w::2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BasMwFET3PoU2QVI9Ti0RZ2FHC@kUBVULidqJipGDGzCB3N1V0oKZzZ83A/Ov99tlSnJdv/qBDGzBCI8ArQSMqgRvC7Jc4tiTsR0rJbrrHNONPnY/D7qjdP89xcQo@fx4p9bW0DCQzrKolOelfHsegTs3TDOJJCYy@3Tu2cJ55/OG9fClRqWhna3EKZvT0rbSdSGv24BQGlQG5pVm85euAztC1BA48OL1UPFPMtvI4Ukk6o3IGk2WaDbU4Jg7kq@/)

---

Recursive:

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 172 bytes

```python
def f(w,l,a,b,A=1,B=-1):
 if not-1<a<w:A=-A;a+=A
 if not-1<b<w:B=-B;b+=B
 if l:print'|%s|'%''.join(' \X/'[[0,A,B,2][(i==a)+2*(i==b)]]for i in range(w));f(w,l-1,a+A,b+B,A,B)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc7RCoIwFAbge59iN7GtHcuN7ELdxfYUgXmxUatFTDFBgt7dpgTGuTl8/D/ndO/h3gYxTZerQ46M8AQDFpTkoGXKaZEg71Boh5RXphoLJVNVGibVn9voMaxLy6Re/Fl0vQ8D/mxeH7zBePdofSAYnU97XNcZKNAgmpp4KQ1lYjsvljaNa3vkkQ@oN@F2JSOl5fJTysEwBZbpuUonR47AM@BwoMlyKflJtFUOswjIVhEZ5HF4vlIOx5gRdPoC)

---

Recursive, alternative print:

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 172 bytes

```python
def f(w,l,a,b,A=1,B=-1):
 if not-1<a<w:A=-A;a+=A
 if not-1<b<w:B=-B;b+=B
 if l:L=[' ']*w;L[a]=' \/'[A];L[b]=[' \/'[B],'X'][a==b];print'|%s|'%''.join(L);f(w,l-1,a+A,b+B,A,B)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc7BCoJAEAbgu0@xlxg3x3IlO7jNYffsAwS2h11KMkSlBAl6d1slMOb0f/MPTP8e7l2bTtP1VrEqHLFBiw4VCdQUC54HrK5Y2w2xONnTmCuKlbQRqT933n1ZSxeRXrzJCyqBgdmOsiitIWCXPZTK@OTMvJqjNghnMKUlckb2z7od4LN5fWADsHt0dRsWXC4/xQJtpNBFGhVqPlXhEUWCAg88WO6Cn3hb5TBLiskqaYKZH5GtlOHRd1I@fQE)

Comment: I am once again amazed by the speed of first answers on code golf challenges. Nice one! :)

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 168 bytes

```python
w,n,r,l=input()
R=L=1
exec"""
d=[~r*R,-~l*L].count
print'|%s|'%''.join(' /\X'[2*d(~x)|d(x+1)]for x in range(w))
if-1<r+R<w:r+=R
else:R=-R
if-1<l-L<w:l-=L
else:L=-L"""*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc7BCoMgHIDxu08RQailjTbYIfINPHkatA6jbHPI3zCjBtGrtyD4br/LN/zCx8F132cGzDMrDAxTIBQpIUWB9KLbOI5RJ@rNp4rxzaayyVs3QUCDNxDwmowrTjDOv84AwdHl@cD1Ne3IttC1I0tW0KZ3PloiA5F/wVuTmVJkel5UPlPVXPpMKKTtqEsluDrFcnmI5UKeIgWXx0gK@35nxRG7/QE)

Comment: [What a weird and unfortunate error, just as if it didn't take precious bytes to define `d`!](https://tio.run/##Jc5PC4IwHMbxu69iCLE/boYFHay9g512CqxD5FaL8ZvMiQbiWzcheG6fw/Ptvukd4LCurbHIkpEDj9zTWkslq7OZzDPP86yVzRKZ5mLxTN3LZxggZV10kPC862e8w7j8BAcEo/3tipsDa8ky0bklU1HRuw0RTcgBig94GTJSmjkrqkss9GWsYyF1ZnxvtlOh/@KF2sQLqf6ipFBbCIPVEuagGxKhdD3xahs//gA)

Answer (score 8):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>240</s> <s>236</s> 208 bytes

```c
#define g(a,b) b?a++,a==x&&(a=x-1,b=0):a--,a==-1&&(a=0,b=1)
i,m,n,o,p,t[]={47,92};f(x,y,r,l){for(m=1,n=0;y--;puts("|"),g(r,m),g(l,n))for(printf("|"),i=0;i<x;o=i==r,p=i++==l,putchar(o*p?88:o?t[m]:p?t[n]:32));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDfboIwFIfveYoGM9OO00mZOkc980E2LyoINoFCKiYY57OzdmzLQnvxpd85/fVPxrNKmXKYaZNVl/xItucu183T6S34r6w2pXfDLD8W2hxJSRUcGDnsVBSBQuznc6qw5wIOGLNUce4tF986dlKwQEMNBhpooXvf4235Aq/JXRa0hytYqNitaCytUYDBWF45l@2lO9PwM2RQUgu1RwWGMd/Xuit1xVjVrl9ve9mgRrTQoo4ixArc/uykLG0e291mkza77r3ep62D2afPCWPyPrgUUittKCO3oKBrEDEIWDJJxtNDJn@1K0z00usE4olOYli5KaYpK1i77mRihU@YZNyDxYK48fdKv@hT8pADuY6wI6oR9Qjj8WFCID@f6r/c5QXDFw)

f() takes parameters as follows:

`x` = width,
`y` = length,
`r` = Initially right-going line starting position
`l` = Initially left-going-line starting position

-4 Bytes. credits  Kevin Cruijssen. Thanks

Comment: You can golf 3 bytes by changing the `while` to a `for` to remove the `{}` and one of the semi-colons. And 1 more byte by changing `c&&d` to `c&d`. [Try it online **236 bytes**.](https://tio.run/##bZHhboIwFIX/8xQNywiE20kZOketvsj@mDK0SYum1QyjPju7LW7ZEihpz/1O7smFSir1ttsNT6qT@tx8kpU7Nerwsl9Hf5FV3c6zQYGEhrdpDxewoMGBya7twab8Qum64MfzyaXxLc7ArmmZJDbPwQXlUOmgNKVggjKorBB9kqRG9JRhQcsM3Ih0QC4gLQRlyJwoUHtiHsQiMZ5kfowjTnpqxwmUKLha9X4mud/aVCbNZrms5ea9rJtN9Va/YpMUSgh7w81B47W@qTwXwvD7gFHEbFWXZuQatekCWAEMKqAlvhkn48fGGf8xvT1lVt4s0Z4yywLmuNh07hwW2FlOeixkTqXeo2g2I@T3bxB8vmry3ADR42H/V@xRhvOji4H4Gyb@ii0DzTBz@AY)

Comment: Looks like you are taking two extra inputs, that is not allowed afaik.

Comment: @O.O.Balance Taking two extra inputs allows me to handle input conditions that original question didn't accounted for, i.e. lines starting in same direction. But if you can point me to a general-consensus vote that says this is disallowed, I'll be happy to remove variables from parameter and add to globals.

Comment: You're not supposed to solve a generalisation of the challenge, but the challenge as specified. Regarding extra inputs, I dug around meta a bit and found this: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12696/79343 I'm thinking it must be written up somewhere else, too, but i can't find it atm. It is however the norm.

Comment: @O.O.Balance I didn't think that was the norm, but I understand objection to passing special values as parameters. I could've initiaized those params in my function with 6 bytes penalty, but I improved the answer instead. Thanks for your inputs :)

Comment: In your g macro, you can golf 2 bytes by changing a==-1 to a<0.

Comment: Actually got more in the macro, a++,a and a--,a can golf 2 bytes each to ++a and --a

Comment: I checked; works on GCC too.

Comment: [187 bytes](https://tio.run/##XZBBboMwEEX3nMKlquQRYwUTkqZ2LS7SjSGBWgKD3FQChZyd2iXtAs/ieb6/vjxTsarVtlmW5/OlNvZCGqqxhLJIEq3UWGjGsFSp4MLf5plqlfqeQ2SwQ4s9DrKmI07osIVb3TvaKY5WpXJiTA7f1y8azzFgQx12AS1agOAz6mlwxl7rX4M072OwV5/aUdorwxzMdFAmSVgLRV8MxT4TtnjLRP4qugdPJwB5X3wK6bSxFMgtqukReYocc5Bk/YCP/5P9w0bOg5xhupGzFA@@@DblgEfvzjYqDwmbjHu02xF//qcMzSjIyxnJtMKtaFd0K2zAh42RPPYaNg1y@QE "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 7):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>66</s> 40 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
｛²Ｘø⁶╵［⁷／²２％［↔｝∔｝；ｘ╷？⁷∔⁷＋╷｝［ｊ｝｝ｎ⁶［|ＰＪｐ|ｐ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjVCJUIyJXVGRjM4JUY4JXUyMDc2JXUyNTc1JXVGRjNCJXUyMDc3JXVGRjBGJUIyJXVGRjEyJXVGRjA1JXVGRjNCJXUyMTk0JXVGRjVEJXUyMjE0JXVGRjVEJXVGRjFCJXVGRjU4JXUyNTc3JXVGRjFGJXUyMDc3JXUyMjE0JXUyMDc3JXVGRjBCJXUyNTc3JXVGRjVEJXVGRjNCJXVGRjRBJXVGRjVEJXVGRjVEJXVGRjRFJXUyMDc2JXVGRjNCJTdDJXVGRjMwJXVGRjJBJXVGRjUwJTdDJXVGRjUw,i=JTVCMiUyQzAlNUQlMEE0JTBBMTA_,v=2)

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>56</s> 50 bytes

```
↷ＰＩθＭ⊕η→ＩθＦ²«Ｊ⊕⎇ιεζ⁰ＦＩθ«✳§⟦↘↙⟧ι∨⁼ＫＫψX¿⁼ＫＫ|«¿ι→←≦¬ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9RS8MwFIWf019x6dMNVKjDp/k0nA8Tp0X2IIgPobtdL3ZJl6TVqfvtNemm4CCB8J2cc@4ta2VLo5phKLg3/ok3tUd5nSy7xnNrWXu8Uc7jTkZoesKFLi1tSXtaYy0zmI6eoBZnvytjAScSvhJx123blflnXZHVyu6RM6AMPmVIyoNJjK7fkOgVx9w5Wyo9G40zv9Br@sCX6dy867E9TBHf91T51ww4hj1avN11qnFYEL1hIPtw0@c0jiYEV3Cup9/pqXFUWcK4799@gVPj6ERj1xEuVTtzjjcaH4yP7ZEeknAOw3CZwxVMIB8u@uYH) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: Saved 6 bytes by reducing reliance on pivoting. Explanation:

```
↷ＰＩθＭ⊕η→Ｉθ
```

Print the sides.

```
Ｆ²«
```

Loop over the two lasers.

```
Ｊ⊕⎇ιεζ⁰
```

Move to the start of the laser.

```
ＦＩθ«
```

Loop over the height.

```
✳§⟦↘↙⟧ι∨⁼ＫＫψX
```

Draw a `\` or `/` in the appropriate direction, unless the square is not empty, in which case draw an `X`.

```
¿⁼ＫＫ|«
```

Have we hit a side?

```
¿ι→←≦¬ι
```

If so then take one step sideways and invert the direction of travel.

Comment: This goes out of bounds when the input is "10 2 4 2"

Comment: @MartijnVissers Well yes, if your width is 2, then your positions can only be 0 or 1...

Answer (score 5):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 186 bytes

```java
(w,h,r,l)->{var x="";for(int i=0,j,R=1,L=-1;i++<h;l+=L,l+=l<0|l>=w?L=-L:0,r+=R,r+=r<0|r>=w?R=-R:0,x+="|\n")for(j=0,x+="|";j<w;j++)x+="/X\\ ".charAt(j==r?j==l?1:R+1:j==l?L+1:3);return x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVDLcoIwFN37FXdYkUmgxKoLY3S6pxu66UztIkUUaEQnRLGjfDu9PLqnk8nJzck595FcXZWX776bWKuyhFeVFXCfAGSFTcxexQmEqkxM2ZEAb9ZkxQF0x7kogoq1mHZoOtREoLbGfb586SyG0iqLx/WU7eCIBdw@y8cnKHMoyZB6qNOnBtm4FUuZYZp46/tVGbhJxxH7k@mqZjJgOYskZ6H0uMgoXaVCUxkyBL0KHnotqw2@hcuAGSqjFgzypuUj6UXI36h0HtvCIW3WXA6EI/JVJXJKSXt9et9uwfHjVJkXiyJpNgh6w5cR5csuDDF4JsIk9mIKuIm6Ef1f/ZQ2Ofqni/XPOK/VhdsP5w/ft2A8YJzNCPmPAS2jDbPWMGXBaMM0YHNcfD7aMWcLrDAdredtP38d1ZO6@QU)

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>177 169</s> 166 bytes

```php
[,$w,$h,$a,$b]=$argv;for($e=-$d=1;$h--;$s[$a+=$d]^L?:$a+=$d=-$d,$s[$b+=$e]^L?:$b+=$e=-$e){$s=str_pad("",$w)."|";$s[$b]="X\/"[$e];$s[$a]="X\/"[$a-$b?$d:0];echo"|$s
";}
```

requires **PHP 7.1** for negative string indexes, **PHP 5.5** or later for indexing string literals.
for **PHP <7.1**, remove `^L`, replace `"X\/"` with `"/X\\"`, `:0` with `+1:1`, `[$e]` with `[$e+1]`, remove `."|"` and insert `|` before the newline. (+3 bytes)
for **PHP < 5.5**, replace `"/X\\"` with `$p` and insert `$p="/X\\";` at the beginning. (+2 bytes)

takes input from command line arguments. Run with `-nr` or [try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/930a3659935f716e5d9aef7d94886dc25b5037c6).

Comment: It's unfortunate that onlinephpfunctions.com does not save the correct PHP version in the sharing link...

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 162 bytes

```python
from numpy import*
def f(w,h,u,v):
 v=w+w-v-1;T=eye(w);M=vstack([T,2*T[::-1]]*2*h)
 for r in M[u:u+h,:]+M[v:v+h,:]:print('|%s|'%''.join(' \/X'[int(i)]for i in r))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVTJjuIwEL37K0pIrcTEEJKGPqTFJ3AaDkgxBwTOMtNZ5GxChG9nvBFI90zPRIry/GzXe1VxuTzXSZG/3m4RLzLIm6w8Q5qVBa@n6MQiiOyOJKQhLQ4QtOvO6WbtzHvfrtmZ2R1@36zbqj4cf9nhlvjTbRgEM2@/n/rTBCOICg4c0hw2YRM0TkKCvbMJ26BVMCh5mte21b9UvfViWfOfRZrbFlB3Z4VyJsV7GSGVETjGt5pVdQVrCC3LoqhLT3USwBt8sDyWyFsAT@OknsUiTizGYiYaRkuEeqAALvQCCBHQwKUaiDGVQHwFEoBK4Pb/tUsYIuL9t6fFyJMnPFElKIWpAVQKghY2MgopIJEGwowBrmFcbVd@v3pa/tWTP/K0QLIGVBvRWtTE3ZmUqS6Tq5boyux0Cs/7Pun7i8HAaqy/GtdkhXRWqgr6uZcIRrxiH7ThNftEK96wz7RMCwb6k9vVYPbtu2L5SNflXpj7AbqfH3N8zOnZ/UHIG4T8706K/Cu7Xr1i8x4h3aPAGULloRZNwdn8WGRl@sHsiYlt05ODh/h6NNK4L4jGDK0ce@7gCZFBf2CEVBcS2X6yFZm4JRg/1MxWDSkvBvFkwoNwMq/YgR8TNYXVRBpBppfIx9wmYnF2KG3R5QSyecyLprQ94pNXssR4WKwviGhCc5PRpbsO@VyS6zibS3Md5XJprzSfPKI9rjJF3X4D)

Comment: I like the formatting in your test suite, reliably showing the inputs against the output... Nice one ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 117 bytes

```ruby
->w,h,a{a[1]-=w;(1..h).map{s=' '*w;a.map!{|x|d=x<0?-1:1;s[x]='X\\/'[s[x][/ /]?d:0];x+=d;x==w ?-1:x<-w ?0:x};?|+s+?|}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NctBDoIwEIXhvaeoKxQG6BDqglq5hsnQRRUNGxMiEGooZ0fbxN3/Zd68p9tne6otvczQgVkMoU7VLA@YZd0xe5l@GVTEoniWxmu/OOtaZc@8TrFCOZDVKro2TR6Rb8pZruu24lraRLXSKjUzP7Xn9Be8squsXTIktVvXjXZ0AuRACKXW8BcHDCqDCuBBBQcBJABFoICTvxUBCIV/@w13OnuYe7e40fXTOLAnxaOWzPe6fQE)

Anonymous lambda taking input as width `w`, height `h` and an array of starting points `a`.

Comment: You kind of made my day by making it an expandable array, not just 2 starting points.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>243</s> <s>233</s> <s>222</s> 205 bytes

```powershell
param($w,$h,$a,$b)$l,$r,$s=1,-1,' \/'
1..$h|%{$p,$p[$b],$p[$a]=[char[]](' '*$w),$s[$r],($s[$l],"x")[!($a-$b)]
if($a+$l-in($z=0..($w-1))){$a+=$l}else{$l*=-1}if($b+$r-in$z){$b+=$r}else{$r*=-1}"|$(-join$p)|"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3BboQgEIbvPgUlfyvsggWz9saTWA7YaNyGdg0ebFZ9djtuahoOw/fPNzPDbWrT2LcxbujcvA0hhS@BSaFXCAqNRFRICqOzSluVs/fXPLNFgX55njEoDDUa/yjBu/qjD6n2XuQsP2GSNFcjeSX2Gr3iP1zWTwJB02afXTv6nhH19Vvg7kxR0GltpZQz5Q5xbePYzognp@26280ZiWzcyWjISH9Gehh8gdCfN@oPcuHrtmbZCzr2xqxhll0yzv@ZkoMvO5fMHFwaVtGz1RFUNFKy8kC7y8xs2y8)

Oooof. those logic blocks are big and dirty and mostly duplicated. The next step would be rewriting them so they don't need the else statement.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>165</s> 164 bytes

```python
w,h,x,y=input()
a,b,s=1,-1,' \/'
exec"""l=[' ']*w
l[x],l[y]=s[a],s[b]if x-y else'X'
if-1<x+a<w:x+=a
else:a=-a
if-1<y+b<w:y+=b
else:b=-b
print'|%s|'%''.join(l)
"""*h
```

Saved a byte thanks to Jonathan Frech.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc3RCoMgFIDhe59CgjitjlvFriLfY@C80GHkEIvZSKF3b41u/@/in9MyTr7d9xVHjJi49fN3KS5EocbAG2QNAn3egJhoXlmWOS6AgixX4kSU6ESSPAglMQgt7UAjS9S4YOABxA6s6WOl@rWLFVfk3zvFmTolVfqQVHF9iuZMk/lj/QJbHjbIAa7vyfrCXchxLsd9v2NTY4v1Dw)

Comment: `\\/` is equivalent to `\/`.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://github.com/ngn/k), 58 bytes

```
{" \\/X|"4,'(+/3!1 2*(x#'e+2*|e:=2*x)(2*x)!z+(!y;-!y)),'4}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcoxDoMwDIXhqzjpEBtCE7sJA1bv0YEVOlRihgJnT4O6/Pr09D7d8l5KmYfdwjiG12GTd9iGh2GQBtebm1ppjml4SrMSXjHfFs2mndmIvEtn2Rl9WL2z42LJXz3dDPcwIPbKURkS6Z8RuDJdFIiVEjVrBs7VWfu6ShWr1Gsk0vID)

anonymous function that accepts three arguments: `x` the width, `y` the length, `z` a pair of starting positions for the lasers

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 169 bytes

```c
A,B,c;f(w,l,a,b){for(A=1,B=-1;l--;a+=A,a<0|a==w?A=-A,a+=A:0,b+=B,b<0|b==w?B=-B,b+=B:0,puts("|"))for(c=-1;c<w;c++)putchar(c<0?'|':a^c?b^c?32:B>0?92:47:b^c?A>0?92:47:88);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc3RasMgFAbg6/UpQm6q5Ajq0q7TuKAPMtAD6QpdN7aOXDR99uyYwBiC5@L8H@cXxRFxnj0EQDuwEc4QIfHb8PHFvFMQnFD2LISNjfMQOzlF58beO0EbRUZCalyARJKy0EFYIpLPn@s3q6ea81yHuQq70WLTcCJ8ixR2st9OWxNfsU80j9qEF9k/a9M@mRz4v@1w4PY@ny7X6j2eLoxvbpuHge2hUpIGqpbbav2x5vYfZS2pXUmTlqQp3y1P7UqjcL9c6VLUWlb23edf)

Comment: [163 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY3basMwDIav26dIc1ObyGC76WF21GA/yMA2ZCv0RNeRi6bPntkNlGGQLvR90q/AvkIYRwMWgu5ID0dw4Omju9yIQQEWmdBHxrSr0IBr@OAQ@zZNyIzi4Cu04JvF9ff@Q8qhpINPCwkjs4rTlBSQSV1Voek1jYvh20XW8HY5LJX7DK2PvZLK7nn7IVW9VQmY97TbUf0cD@d7cXKHM6Hzx3zWkQ0UgseGoqa6mP6XVP9TyeaqnpSMNlcy8vWrxDp3EW5eVzI3YgrL857jHw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>322</s> <s>311</s> 302 bytes

Changed how I put laser direction in string for 11 bytes.
Moved assignment out of when for 9 bytes.

```
{w:Int,h:Int,r:Int,l:Int->{var a=""
var f=r
var d=1>0
var s=l
var t=!d
for(o in 1..h){a+="|"
for(c in 0..w-1)a+=when{c==f&&c==s->"X"
c==f&&d||c==s&&t->"\\"
c==f||c==s->"/"
else->" "}
a+="|\n"
if(d){if(++f==w){--f
d=!d}}else if(--f<0){f=0
d=!d}
if(t){if(++s==w){--s
t=!t}}else if(--s<0){s=0
t=!t}}
a}()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xRlrUxvJ8fv@ikGVwtJZaAUYPlAWV1zsVKhyDpfDxVRF/jDSjqQp9nUzs8gc8Nud7p7HzkoyOJcPcRmh7e2efr@G28rksvyW/sT@qgQ3ImOLSjGzkprNq0ywZZUv2HzF81yUS3GWrIyp9Vma4kt8N9KGz2/FV0CB96N5VaS/N0IbWZU6PTw9PD0@Sq7XFcu5FkqzmTBrIUpmAFRIpSqlk@TzihsmF2wt2IrfCcaBtVIyA0HgvFpJDWJVCyKquUJZck/9c5I8svDv8f/zkPxarYcovl7JEuUnbVlWrUsmzWg0IiGnHeJp56Rp59hph8e0w3Da4T7tiDKNH9LoIUUhr1ZDllfV7YhdGjarmnIusiEz1ZqrTIPLBRMlAlZCiVHHK5nia7K@8@Ivv11DYMhyyWRJhFVdV1oawJRKzNH5P7cqp5HKaaRyGmmZRiqnkcpppHIaqZzGKk87Kk8jlf9eFKTQPQiWla8M00IUoDIrhDBeVXYNmr7CeC/vRClFaUaMlF/xuhalRiPMKrPy2ht@K1hTk@KaF/BR87mIFCbe3sdp5ONIe3YTax/5OI18nEY@TiOF01jhaezjS7aE7ENvgvxrrlmthDH3rJrdyarRQ7ZqViDpO3Aoug9U0Og0vlS8gOy8B53LjMlAl/NZpZCS9Y1qtAHDsaqk@jAYsY9CgY000xWAqVzMqybPIPAh7KmQNJigKN1nheHRIoIPqsbUjdmZ1ZBMEgyOryhQQdYhxJoB82N4geTWFyM6@7LEc/pwAuEs4cXgLPE2ugY3rWUGx2EJWYlQXDoYWN6eQfmn4Yr4UpxDfHtMJZcrc2CTwWZ9/w@hqgNZZuIr5leBVpshA@uW0gozePnoXCz@/MkfVTUHeOByuQhlCbxLUtsUHqKr1hJsN7OJDvxLF9PopaCk9bsAt@Z5RdEDjUOMvsMBhf9xBoT94@fPQdeyMjYTJeaulplY83v4YkTdcrRdyaKE0jRkMwgXpCe4N3uHU5vvjCuo6KbNdrL/EBIEYo2BIA0UCXUwB1zIaULEuolI9sQrCvNw@AWIqFA7ivCiyY2sc0G6tt56z@crAgEyRIdmmJVQnbWl4qyWtUDtFJ8bjIzHNp4@bUUkapAJUBjaKKQ4ZzNo2UzDyxXrT1vKD5sBt0UIKY3dwtOmg04OtQnqgrjtGBAR8UFdq1k7XZRYbsplw5fCpvWrDGxwS0ECdZtdX16hTW6tmS6MEUVt8OVCfkWPu16kCywlkBplU8xACRBkdm/AuMk1QpElfKdUOWOnLvHP2OE4zmV4jvLvjL1JbGdxlX3qq3ra9qa2L4We5PvRC1QvCzPuCHMIwoTuGTrnNDSRaWgg0zAgTMNwME1Dz/UdJ3XdJo2EefNdYY46wowT1HpqJbBMpu7AG6eka1m2WVlb3FjZYzrP@GgcOJ90GZ90rXCSxOOS64Gbg1OAdkeoAO0OUwHaHasCNLLPSZDy9DnzHCXWEt4UPkh8jLgQcRFyE3M4DByOnosGdMDNI/38lCZJmrJ33MAIDZmn3TCPWbzgUGoY5IGBrpm1GJgU/TueM8f1soTBCJ9XAnlaAGUcAlULo2cUhB4HxPn91xoqFST5HSR91MrCAsEW0M2p2rLftEASyyYI2vZh34OHJDQiIDop4ys5okG9qaA4Up0ZUp10c0VEoKq1rwaaGo5UUDQUVoNQQqFCNaWE3WWUgIxQ3ql/9mOrxBaJLUHWaS1xBi2dKvwDjj4gAgAlz@UfwgojNHjCHdA2/f2oQVkyaoo735Oa3mJWMUsC9gBd9YY1Uyv40CuFOwmZn2gOz8cWXzW21NoVDGsmYbG91t79vWxgqWQJnZbTWrbguW4pj221xZp@x6GFlHoN1p2wXs9BrOEnVn8HazlMUB4Hda6dkCUcjGJhEskEcJS@77wOTeBwNLIKD6wHSN6PjWknDZwW3KiJBHWOo4izqScQ2ILnVd4Upe8sFAu7rEgEupkZjCXUIrJOA87Pd1mHedu8BuM89ghCmrRMx6MR8Tw4HCSu0wKjiyyzjhcCUy0K4dKNU3bCcBSBS9KurOsV7OAPSQShkz8jGA@IOvdcVRrm8draT6pNmk7Td7tjjOK0mUyc4/f3I5Dz8MF5h4Sx3k3v@8IJiWzaUZOYkvuk2ZJOu0VVuQzAEDE/KGcblY@PGwKybSWAgIJzW5npdFubKxRhLbUYWmfsVGq4pY5pNbKRXP0XKj0@/ojp0@@YvtwtIvHnmxQ03XelEVglDs5Zj/Ui@BNiowW2MtXWx52pug8KlVKvPImv8TCTYyGD9b66c@utU52EHsFkn3Qs6fBccMhyrkQB@393MfAkHG9H5AJJV9bgTrAQVjhXh3IAk/p8RXckne1jFLseX3kCJ4t3ayZ2CkNSBCVeEqaVotW7I8xWHZqW1jtwdD@gYSG17kLw69euhE/cwhneMnZwQO/Cc1zYOzU7@F5alzzZ@MDz3RnsLRu3R/uuMU5ePNgf61X@R3VnO288KmAs7AqCYKfy@@bv2j347znz77R7twwQxrNB4ImeEWZDCk/xA8Kg5bF@bfraN@GdzrYvA8A3Z/z9ko/duR0nh4bvvbx1YHscfcN@beeRT8I0qnSXNwVs1Lhquk3bT0OujHCSGAescIekLLVNhISOdl2extpPTdkdY@2MWHBZ9rla6jN2oRS/f2vnvvNBmPw@8GKW8TD0Bkn8CNGH6gbzwZznFt/1b7E5RuPWDwMODBOu6VN91ZZoH28GcNSgOwRqhHRLUJX5fVwCBWzM7ZyIL2CgknyWwyjBC6AEMXK0F0dLVOV9UTWORVDAzzGwE9Ig40/yCBbdmVMbbmz0Qmu8r8VowH6tjDhzt4ToJxhcLAnPMopp3ClIjUajKFoUEnqWv7SBIM8qoctXjsrd77RjcNj27fyZs5pN0IPH4yML//awPsOZfUWfij5z/Dw4f6B5dQKDKo2pE0W/swkOpDSOTnL6bSZ7WQKe7Fd@2hw88NcTnOEQOveTG0xtAMbe9jCfTBb7@/CpD85xtrHP2eMjgvb3gTkNCQi2MABAH8Z0gW@s95QQAyzOctHPBg/wCWV4MlkPHqBcJhmI9PTksgsL6Nvx4GExGdsXSGMcjXY0OgE1TEyjkUYDjX2R8Kf@4Okbmfla3YNPeeZ7qrW1DTUfygAvRtYr/xJKLu7tRRiivwkEa5zUdC3mciEhikMmhsl837f9rUtRKNTShxf9qYm9kxrGARvitNCiOO2GxUsXJC7tF6oq2FKUQnFjiyCKa0C1h7DeejknpO4HCMT@YG9vBHyk6YMfBqOC11EFhDNMBcEDlgpF1J0x0rjw7U3YG39JZlY4o1xCBVny/EItG0yN91/nokYF@9FQ1PusKpCwDWnusPVeb7DJ6N9HX7CK4nQXQc4n4Wn85U9I8Mle@ULO4U6JBt/F@niL9fH/zvoDXQbv4ExXrnnZ77ml/C8PLZ@ncFnSex0O67UYh4DhVvbdCEd0BO7wLez4y9MG67rfshyy9vB2Um/PG0ZGGQxcR7iCUd9rPbStCrrIZib5@xqXHXRpw/4GQUxbKT4PoX/vDn9fgl0OPB/@T1D0YShgfYFIZ@wa3YQtwTflYPNfYJ2V@IeWoSvNTsQQkpg/JCku7FKbq0Wf7pZOh9At4GcImdCaKX6FbwdDC3pjQUcA3cQ@AvgJ/T888ejwcErYR5vYh/YQPGfQ7tY0UOA6j4K2g8d2ZCGCXb53RhaFDuHYq4ZdwdXiKIviw4tg@OCjK46vlrG9@HIM4lWwPdOh4FlOyzAWua9Q3@w8g8NK8u0/)